# Impala UPPER doesn't uppercase special characters

Tags: sql, impala

I'm trying to apply UPPER on various columns in a table, but it uppercases only the latin-like strings.

For example:

```sql
SELECT UPPER('Glück')
```

returns:

```
GLüCK
```

Is there any way to uppercase all characters?

Comment: Perhaps a locale/regional setting is needed?

Comment: What happens if you do `UPPER(N'Glück')`?

Comment: can  you use hive? Hive is giving correct uppercase  `GLÜCK`